# Redis: RESP Protocol client query processing

Tags: redis, redis-server

I am trying to reimplement redis in C++. When the client gets the query, should it simply serialize the query and send it or check the correctness on the client side itself and then send the query, if it is correct? It is not that clear from the documentation [here](http://redis.io/topics/protocol).

Comment: It's up to the client developer. most clients allow free-style queries without any parsing and validation at all

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer How is the server supposed to handle queries?

Comment: Do you mean you are rewriting Redis in c++ or just a client library?

Comment: @TheRealBill rewriting Redis.